# Return which image from a vertical list is currently in the viewport with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a vertical list of images that a user scrolls to view. How can I make jQuery tell me which image is in the viewport? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a fiddle that will get you close to what you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/Y6pjG/

What it does is just change the border if the image is more than 30 pixels from the top.
To get what you want just change the if statement to also check position from the bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // check on page load
    doCheck();
    // check on scroll
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        doCheck();
    });

});

function doCheck(){
    $('#list li').each(function(index){
        var item = $(this);
        if((item.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) > 30){
            item.css('border-style', 'solid');
        }else{
            item.css('border-style', 'none');
        }
    });
}
```